# Trying to compare file data to String

Tags: java, while-loop, contains

I am trying to return whether a string occurs in any of the lines of a file, and print out the line it occurs in if there is one.

Currently, in the console, it prints output from both my `if` and `else` statements. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I want `true` or `false`, not both values. This is what I get in the console:

> ```
> 0: -
> String False
> 1: File String, ThisString
> String False
> ```

Here's my method:

```
public void checkString() {
    int line = 0;
    //fileString = false;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line + ": " + str);
        line++;
        if (str.contains(string)) {
            System.out.println("File String," + string);
            fileString = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("String False");
        }
    }
}
```

There is obviously additional code, this is the section I am hung up on. It follows a path to a specific file I have it reading from. More specifics on the question: I want to perform an action if code is true and a completely different action if false or in the `else` statement.

Comment: Well, you're in a loop, and the first time through the loop it prints one thing, and the second time it prints something else.  So that's why you see two outputs.  It sounds like you want to print something outside the loop, instead of inside, but your question is totally unclear and I have no idea what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I was trying to get the code to read through a file in which I have done. I then want the code to compare each Line to a String var I have declared in my class. If the line .contains my string or vice versa, I want it tell me that the string exist within the file, if it doesn't then I want it to tell me that it does not exist. I was attempting that process above in simple code and got a little confused.

Comment: So if the line contains the string, then you know the file contains the string so you don't have to read any more of the file, right?  You can use a `break` statement.  On the other hand, you can't tell that the file doesn't contain the string until you've read the entire file.  So the line that says that the file doesn't contain the string can't be printed until after the loop.

Comment: Hi Cameron, please take a look at the changes I've made to your question. I've rephrased a few things and improved the formatting - I think it should be clearer this way and your likelihood of getting good answers should improve. Obviously, feel free to edit it again if you feel it can be improved further.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could go about finding the line containing your string is like this:

```
public String lineContaining(String someString) {
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String eachLine = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(lineNumber + ": " + eachLine);
        lineNumber++;
        if (eachLine.contains(someString)) {
            System.out.println("Found string " + someString
                    + " in line " + lineNumber + ": " + eachLine);
            return eachLine;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method will go through each line (supplied by your `scanner`) and check whether it contains `someString`. If there is such a line, it will return it (thus exiting out of the `while` loop); if not, the method returns `null`, meaning there was no line containing what you were looking for. You can call this from wherever you need that line, perform a null check (`== null`) on the result to see whether a line was found, and proceed accordingly from there. If you need more information, such as the line number your string was found in, I would recommend creating a simple wrapper object that has a string (the line your substring was found in) and an integer (the line number); then your method can return that wrapper instead of a `String`.

Note that I've renamed your `line` variable to `lineNumber` (in my opinion, `line` would sound like it's a string, not an int), and `str` to `eachLine` (a habit from Smalltalk, which emphasises the iterative nature of the variable).